# How to unittest ejb 2 classes

Tags: java, unit-testing, ejb

What kind of tools and techniques exist for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with your [question on JSPs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398423/how-to-unit-test-logic-in-jsp/1398460), you have two options:

In Container Testing (again [Cactus](http://jakarta.apache.org/cactus/) can help here) or out of container testing (mocking & stubbing any dependencies). This [article](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/02/05/automate_ejb.html) appears to go over both options. Once again I'm going to recommend [JUnit In Action](http://www.manning.com/massol/).